# App Lost all selection info of navigation and tab, after update a AppStorage state

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-tabview

I want to realize a function which could change the color scheme of app.

However, whenever I click theme style in ThemeView, it will pop to SettingsView and Tab will reselect to Home.

Is there a way that I can change the color scheme of app, and still stay in ThemeView?

AppTabView.swift

```swift
public enum ThemeStyle: Int, CaseIterable {
   
  case automatic
  case light
  case dark
}

extension View {
   
  @ViewBuilder
  func themeStyle(_ themeStyle: ThemeStyle) -> some View {
    switch themeStyle {
    case .automatic:
      self
    case .light:
      preferredColorScheme(.light)
    case .dark:
      preferredColorScheme(.dark)
    }
  }
}

struct AppTabView: View {
   
  @AppStorage(StorageKeys.themeStyle) private var themeStyle: ThemeStyle = .automatic
   
  var body: some View {
    TabView(selection: $tabItem) {
      Text("First Tab")
        .tabItem {
          Label("Home", systemImage: .house)
        }
      NavigationView {
        SettingsView()
      }
      .tabItem {
        Label("Settings", systemImage: .gearshapeFill)
      }
    }
    .themeStyle(themeStyle)
    .toggleStyle(SwitchToggleStyle(tint: .accentColor))
  }
}
```

SettingsView.swift

```swift
struct SettingsView: View {
  var body: some View {
    List {
      Section {
        NavigationLink {
          ThemeView()
        } label: {
          Label("TITLE_THEME", systemImage: .circleLefthalfFill)
        }
    }
    .navigationTitle("TITLE_SETTINGS")
    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
  }
}
```

ThemeView.swift

```swift
struct ThemeView: View {
   
  @AppStorage(StorageKeys.themeStyle) private var themeStyle: ThemeStyle = .automatic
   
  @ViewBuilder
  private func text(_ themeStyle: ThemeStyle) -> some View {
    switch themeStyle {
    case .automatic:
      Text("TITLE_THEME_AUTOMATIC")
    case .light:
      Text("TITLE_THEME_LIGHT")
    case .dark:
      Text("TITLE_THEME_DARK")
    }
  }
   
  @ViewBuilder
  private func image(_ themeStyle: ThemeStyle) -> some View {
    switch themeStyle {
    case .automatic:
      Image(systemName: .circleLefthalfFill)
    case .light:
      Image(systemName: .sunMax)
    case .dark:
      Image(systemName: .moon)
    }
  }
   
  var body: some View {
    List {
      ForEach(ThemeStyle.allCases, id: \.rawValue) { value in
        Button {
          themeStyle = value
        } label: {
          HStack {
            Label {
              text(value)
                .foregroundColor(.label)
            } icon: {
              image(value)
            }
            if themeStyle == value {
              Spacer()
              Image(systemName: .checkmark)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    .navigationTitle("TITLE_THEME")
    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
  }
}
```

Is there a way that I can change the color scheme of app, and still stay in ThemeView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ViewBuilder` breaks identity by making a branch (inside the `switch statement`. Instead, use a ternary operator and do not branch. You can still use a `switch` inside a convenience function outside of the `ViewBuilder`.

```
private func preferredColorSchemeBasedOnTheme(_ themeStyle: ThemeStyle) -> ColorScheme? {
  switch themeStyle {
    case .automatic:
      return nil
    case .light:
      return .light
    case .dark:
      return .dark
    }
}

@ViewBuilder func themeStyle(_ themeStyle: ThemeStyle) -> some View {
  preferredColorScheme(preferredColorSchemeBasedOnTheme(themeStyle))
}
```

For information on why this happens, I suggest watching Demystify SwiftUI from WWDC: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/